# Closed complex differential forms

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms, kahler-manifolds

I'm trying to make sense of a fundamental definition of Kahler manifolds. In almost any introduction, it is say that given a hermitian metric $g(X,Y)$ and an almost complex structure $J$ such that $J^2=-I$, one can define a complex (1,1)-form $\omega(X,Y)$ = $g(JX,Y)$ = $g(X,JY)$. I understand the effect of $J$ is to rotate a vector i.e. to multiply the components by $i$. It is then stated that the Kahler metric is closed: $d\omega = 0$. What I'm trying to understand is how this statement translates to vectors that lie uniquely in along the real or the imaginary components.

Let's say that the real components have a metric tensor $h$, and the imaginary components have a metric tensor $k$. Is the equation $d\omega = 0$ the same as saying that $dh = -dk$? How would $h$ and $k$ relate to $g$?

Comment: First of all, the metric is a symmetric (or hermitian, in the complex case) covariant tensor of order $2$, and the Kähler form is a differential $2$-form (so a skew-symmetric tensor); the Kähler *form* $\omega = \frac{\sqrt{-1}}2 \sum h_{i\bar j} dz^i\wedge d\bar z^j$ is closed. It makes no sense to say the Kähler metric $g=\sum h_{i\bar j} dz^i\otimes d\bar z^j$ is closed. Now, the real part of $g$ is the associated Riemannian metric and the imaginary part of $g$ is the Kähler form $\omega$.

Comment: Notice that the term "Hermitian metric" is used for both the complex valued metric and its real part, which is a constant danger of confusion.

Comment: Thanks for your replies. The 2-form is usually expressed in terms of $z$ and $\bar{z}$. If I wanted to express it instead in terms of $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$ variables instead of $\mathbb{C}^n$, would I be able to recover the expression I asked for ($dg = dh^{Re} = -dk^{Im}$)?